# Issue related with modifying the value in an NSMutablearray

Tags: ipad, nsmutablearray, xcode4.3, nsmutablecopying

I am facing an issue with the values in NSMutablearray. I have two NSMutablearray, both are holding the same content using mutablecopy. The issue is that when I modify a value in one array, the corresponding value in the second array also get modified. How to resolove this. Please help me.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutableCopy copies by reference, not value. So, any change to one of those objects affects for both arrays.

You could realize different methods to overcome this situation.

// first method

```
nameArray2 = [NSMutableArray new];
[nameArray2 addObjectsFromArray:nameArray1];
```

// second method

```
nameArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:nameArray1 copyItems:YES];
```

Best regards.